# ASP.Net - Calling javascript in User Control server side method

Tags: javascript, user-controls

I have a user control with a public method:

```
    public void ShowDetails(Guid requestGuid)
    {            
        Label1.Text = reportGuid.ToString(); //only for testing            

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "ShowEmailPreview", "alert('hi');", true);
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowEmailPreview", "alert('hi');", true); //doesn't work
        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowEmailPreview", "alert('hi');", true); //doesn't work
    }
```

When hosting page for this user control calls ShowDetails(), I need to call some javascript.

I tried with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript but it doesn't work... However if I add an UpdatePanel on my control and add script for UpdatePanel as shown above, it works well.

I don't want to add UpdatePanel onto my control just for the sake of calling javascript.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually changing your code as following should work.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "ShowEmailPreview", "alert('hi');", true);
```

Comment: This solution changed my week.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "ScriptName", "alert('hi');", true);
```

this is a shorter version